# How do I make a condition to find out if the 2nd or 1st item in a list was selected?

Tags: python

I have these points

```
[(3, 4), (3, 6), (3, 8), (4, 5), (4, 7), (5, 1), (5, 5), (7, 3), (7, 5), (8, 5)]
```

and I conducted some operations on them, to finally get this list

```
[(6.0, 3.605551275463989), (6.324555320336759, 5.385164807134504), (7.211102550927978, 7.280109889280518), (5.0990195135927845, 5.0), (5.830951894845301, 6.708203932499369), (5.0, 4.0), (4.123105625617661, 5.656854249492381), (2.23606797749979, 6.324555320336759), (2.23606797749979, 7.211102550927978), (1.4142135623730951, 8.06225774829855)]
```

The first item in the list, for example `(6.0, 3.605551275463989)` corresponds to the first point, for example `(3,4`). I found the minimum between the two items in the first item of the list and came up with this:

```
[3.605551275463989, 5.385164807134504, 7.211102550927978, 5.0, 5.830951894845301, 4.0, 4.123105625617661, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951]
```

what I want to do now is for example, if the minimum turned out to be the 2nd item, as it did in the first case, I want to write it as follows: `(3,4) M2`, M2 meaning it was the 2nd item. How do I do this? I don't even know where to start with this problem because I haven't run into anything similar.

Comment: Something like ```if min(i) == minimumvalues[0]' ``` ?

Comment: given a single tuple, e.g. `(6.0, 3.605551275463989)` you can find the minimum, do you know how you can find whether it is the first or the second element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip()` to loop over all 3 lists in parallel. Then just compare the selected value from the item in the 2nd list with the corresponding value in the third list to know whether to print `M1` or `M2`.

```
l1 = [(3, 4), (3, 6), (3, 8), (4, 5), (4, 7), (5, 1), (5, 5), (7, 3), (7, 5), (8, 5)]
l2 = [(6.0, 3.605551275463989), (6.324555320336759, 5.385164807134504), (7.211102550927978, 7.280109889280518), (5.0990195135927845, 5.0), (5.830951894845301, 6.708203932499369), (5.0, 4.0), (4.123105625617661, 5.656854249492381), (2.23606797749979, 6.324555320336759), (2.23606797749979, 7.211102550927978), (1.4142135623730951, 8.06225774829855)]
l3 = [3.605551275463989, 5.385164807134504, 7.211102550927978, 5.0, 5.830951894845301, 4.0, 4.123105625617661, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951]

for i1, (m1, m2), selected in zip(l1, l2, l3):
    if selected == m1:
        which = "M1"
    else:
        which = "M2"
    print(i1, which)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
points = [(3, 4), (3, 6), (3, 8), (4, 5),
          (4, 7), (5, 1), (5, 5), (7, 3), (7, 5), (8, 5)]

results = [(6.0, 3.605551275463989), (6.324555320336759, 5.385164807134504), (7.211102550927978, 7.280109889280518), (5.0990195135927845, 5.0), (5.830951894845301, 6.708203932499369), (5.0, 4.0), (4.123105625617661, 5.656854249492381), (2.23606797749979, 6.324555320336759),
           (2.23606797749979, 7.211102550927978), (1.4142135623730951, 8.06225774829855)]

assert(len(points) == len(results))

for i, r in enumerate(results):
    if r[1] < r[0]:
        num = 2
    else:
        num = 1
    print(f'{points[i]}, M{num}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = [(6.0, 3.605551275463989), (6.324555320336759, 5.385164807134504), (7.211102550927978, 7.280109889280518), (5.0990195135927845, 5.0), (5.830951894845301, 6.708203932499369), (5.0, 4.0), (4.123105625617661, 5.656854249492381), (2.23606797749979, 6.324555320336759), (2.23606797749979, 7.211102550927978), (1.4142135623730951, 8.06225774829855)]
b = [(3, 4), (3, 6), (3, 8), (4, 5), (4, 7), (5, 1), (5, 5), (7, 3), (7, 5), (8, 5)]
for i in range(len(a)):
    j = list(a[i])
    print(f'{b[i]}-->{max(j)},M{j.index(max(j))+1}')
```

I converted every tuple to an list and use the list methods...

Output

```py
(3, 4)-->6.0,M1
(3, 6)-->6.324555320336759,M1
(3, 8)-->7.280109889280518,M2
(4, 5)-->5.0990195135927845,M1
(4, 7)-->6.708203932499369,M2
(5, 1)-->5.0,M1
(5, 5)-->5.656854249492381,M2
(7, 3)-->6.324555320336759,M2
(7, 5)-->7.211102550927978,M2
(8, 5)-->8.06225774829855,M2
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
lst1 = [(3, 4), (3, 6), (3, 8), (4, 5), (4, 7), (5, 1), (5, 5), (7, 3), (7, 5), (8, 5)]
lst2 = [(6.0, 3.605551275463989), (6.324555320336759, 5.385164807134504), (7.211102550927978, 7.280109889280518), (5.0990195135927845, 5.0), (5.830951894845301, 6.708203932499369), (5.0, 4.0), (4.123105625617661, 5.656854249492381), (2.23606797749979, 6.324555320336759), (2.23606797749979, 7.211102550927978), (1.4142135623730951, 8.06225774829855)]

for i, pt in enumerate(lst2):
    argmin = pt.index(min(pt))
    print(lst1[i], 'M{}'.format(argmin + 1))
```

Output:

```
(3, 4) M2
(3, 6) M2
(3, 8) M1
(4, 5) M2
(4, 7) M1
(5, 1) M2
(5, 5) M1
(7, 3) M1
(7, 5) M1
(8, 5) M1
```